# Sitecore 9 JSS Campaigns and Goals

Tags: sitecore, jss, sitecore9

I've just started working with Sitecore 9.1 JSS.
From an external site, I make a RESTful API call to a Sitecore item like

```
http://site/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={KEY}
```

I created a campaign and invoked the above with the parameter:

```
https:/site/?sc_camp=<campaignid>&sc_lang=en
```

When I view campaigns in the Experience Analytics dashboard, no campaigns show up. (I did reindex)

I read this article: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/services/tracking and also added the patch file as stated:

```
<configuration>
    <sitecore>
        <settings>
             <setting name="Sitecore.JSS.TrackerServiceEnabled" value="true" />
        </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

What am I missing? How do I trigger campaigns (and even goals) using Sitecore 9.1 JSS?

Answer (score 0):

I pulled an answer from [this blog by Gary Wenneker](https://gary.wenneker.org/sitecore-jss-triggering-marketing-events/):

> ### Deploying the marketing definitions
>
> Before we're able to trigger an event we have to deploy the marketing
>   definitions. This is done from the control panel (Dashboard -> Control
>   Panel). Click on the Deploy marketing definitions link. This will open
>   a window with all the marketing definitions. Select them all and click
>   Deploy. This might take about 15 minutes to run so don't think your
>   system renders unresponsive and please don't be impatient :-)
>
> ### Sitecore JSS Tracking API
>
> The Tracking API can track several things by making a request to the
>   Sitecore Layout Service. It accepts an array of specific types (with
>   their properties)
>
> ```
> const trackingApiOptions = {
>     host: config.sitecoreApiHost,
>     querystringParams: {
>         sc_apikey: config.sitecoreApiKey, 
>     }, 
>     fetcher: dataFetcher
> }; 
>
> const track = (event: string) => {
>     return function (dispatch: any, getState: any) {
>         trackingApi
>             // note the events are an array - batching is supported
>             .trackEvent([{ eventId: event }], trackingApiOptions)
>             .then(() => {
>                 dispatch(artistSearchedClickedRequest);
>             })
>             .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The Tracking API Options object will provide the host, the Sitecore
>   API key (by query string) and a data fetcher. This data fetcher will
>   be a simple implementation of Axios but feel free to use whatever
>   implementation you want:
>
> ```
> import axios from "axios";
>
> export function dataFetcher(url, data) {
>   return axios({
>     url,
>     method: data ? 'POST' : 'GET',
>     data,
>     withCredentials: true,
>   });
> }
> ```